# Editing code with security issues or performance issues

Tags: discussion, review, edits, code

I often edit code on stackoverflow when I see a security issue or a big performance issue that can be changed without altering the meaning of the answer, so in all fairness I would call it an useful edit

I will even add a js fiddle so the code can be run to see that there is indeed no difference in the output

However reviewers will automatically reject the edit when they see a code change according to the implicit guidelines

Even though I post a comment to explain about the issue, the answers are usually old and already accepted so posting a new answer just to warn about another answer with a different code doesn't seem like the right approach since my answer will be very low and probably disregarded

The original writer of the answer is either not around anymore to fix the issue or will not fix it correctly even with guidance, hence my edit

However all this taken into account, my edits are still rejected 80% of the time...

What should I do?

Comment: You should look at the existing questions on MSO on this topic, eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339344/4014959

Comment: Thanks, that makes some good points

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25117798

Here is an example, where the reviewer tried to fix the issue I raised but didn't succeed, hence my reedit but still the same reviewers that reviewed the previous edit are rejecting it

Comment: Reviewers aren't always experts in the stuff they review. But apart from that, when they see a suggested edit on code posted by a 100k+ user, they're likely to assume that the original author has more expertise than the editor. In theory, anyone should be able to edit any post, but generally, people are touchy about code edits.

Answer (score 7):

You don't.

You post your own answer, referencing the other post, and explaining *why* your answer works better and where.

We respect the intent of the poster in edits.

Comment: My point is I respect the intent, posting another answer for 2 lines of difference that will never be seen makes no sense? Why would I clutter the question with yet another answer? There is a ton of SO questions where there is 20+ answers with all very similar codes.. Is this really what we want to see?

Comment: In this case- sure. But you can build on it to explain *how* those two lines help - for more observant future users

Comment: I think that this is an appropriate approach.  You submit your code as an answer, including your improvements, and explain why you believe your answer best meets the post'ers needs.  even if your answer is not accepted, other users may see it and benefit from the knoledge that you are sharing.  It's definitely more polite than simply editing someone else's answer.

Comment: It's actually one what I feel is a teaching moment

Answer (score 2):

The best guidance seems to be here: ["Editing a Question to Include a Comment Left by Asker"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254528/3648282) and here: ["What if editing my answer makes comments seem out of context?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389269/3648282):

Comment on the question or the answer explaining the problem, the OP or someone with editing privileges can make the edit; and you won't get the rejection.

Generally speaking, altering the code provided requires people to very carefully scrutinize the modification and also decide if it's dependant on something else (such as the compiler version).

Your comment should not be deleted as "no longer necessary" if an edit isn't made, unless your comment is clearly incorrect. While you *could* be flagged for incorrect (or nuisance) comments you'll be edit banned quicker from having edits repeatedly rejected.

Maybe the moderator or a recognized expert will incorporate your comment into the post (and mention your contribution). What you can't *afford* is an 80% rejection rate.

Comment: I agree but comments are a terrible way to point to code, it's unreadable..
Maybe a feature to suggest an edit directly to the person who answered would make more sense in those few cases than a review queue, he would be a best judge of "keeping the intent"

Comment: @Tofandel Rob makes a good point: if you persist with a high edit rejection rate you may incur a ban on being able to suggest edits. You can suggest small edits through comments; the main thing is to clearly explain why the edit is necessary. Hopefully, the author will agree & make the edit... but that doesn't always happen. Some people will refuse modifications to their code, even when you point out that they have a classic SQL injection vulnerability. :(

Comment: It's not so much that they refuse, sometimes they try but sadly fail to fix the issue...

Comment: Tofandel, you can make a Feature Request but I don't see how an it would differ from the current mechanism except that you want to target the reviewer. In your question you wrote: `"The original writer of the answer is either not around anymore to fix the issue or will not fix it correctly even with guidance, hence my edit."` --- It seems like your *only* objective is to avoid a rejection (which in the case of an 80% rejection rate is an excellent idea), you can obtain that result by following the advice in JG's and my answer. You can also simply continue, you might have only one more chance.